# jdbcTemplate classCastException during Mockito.when thenReturn

Tags: java, mockito

My problem is that I got `classCastException` during unit test with `Mockito`.( I am newbie with Mockito)

```
    Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(eq("select * from V_MONITORING"),
                                 eq(namedParameters),
                                 eq(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<> 
 (V_MONITORING_Record.class)))).thenReturn((List <V_MONITORING_Record> ) rec);
```

> Without cast it doesn't compile, but with cast I got the exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: ...V_MONITORING_Record cannot be cast to class java.util.List (...V_MONITORING_Record is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you post sample code

Comment: I doubt that a single record can be cast to a list unless it itself is a list. That is also what the error is telling you. Your `V_MONITORING_Record` isn't a `java.util.List` so casting to a list won't work. You probably want `thenReturn(Collections.singletonList9rec));` instead. Wrap your result in a list.

Comment: Why you are casting object into list please use Arrays.asList("rec") .

Comment: Sorry I overlooked it. You are right.Thank you.

Comment: Javadocs say that method returns a List: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-

Answer (score 0):

I think yopu should Use `Arrays.asList(rec)` method so that you can return as List of  `V_MONITORING_Record.class` .

```
Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(eq("select * from V_MONITORING"),
                                 eq(namedParameters),
                                 eq(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<> 
 (V_MONITORING_Record.class)))).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(rec));
```

Comment: No, it returns a List.  I would do the right thing.